# How to implement getter setter methods for changing key values in dynamic methods?

Tags: ruby

Read a csv format file and construct a new class with the name of the file dynamically. So if the csv is persons.csv, the ruby class should be person, if it's places.csv, the ruby class should be places 
Also create methods for reading and displaying each value in "csv" file and values in first row of csv file will act as name of the function. 
Construct an array of objects and associate each object with the row of a csv file. 
For example the content of the csv file could be 
name,age,city 
Chris,23,NYC 
Matt,23,SFO

I have found out a solution to this problem and code works efficiently for this, I am only facing issue while updating new key values being accessed. I also want to update values like :

```
p k.call 'name'
p k.call 'age'
p k.call 'city'
k.name = 'XYZ' # updating new key values
k.age = 25  # updating new key values
p k.call 'name'
p k.call 'age'
```

I am getting error at runtime :

```
undefined method `name' for #<Input:0x00007fb6c20d75c0>
```

Can someone please suggest, what is the correct way to implement getter setter method in this situation ?

```
require 'csv'

class ReadCsv
  attr_accessor :arr
  def initialize(source_name)
    @klass = Class.new
    class_name = File.basename(source_name, ".csv").capitalize
    Object.const_set(class_name, @klass)
    csv_read(source_name)
    method_def
  end

  def csv_read(source_name)
    @arr = CSV.read(source_name).transpose
  end

  def method_def
    @klass_obj = @klass.new
    arr.each { |method_name, *a| @klass_obj.define_singleton_method(method_name.to_s) { a } }
  end

  def universal_attr_accessor(entity, attr_name) #change added
    definition_method_name = "define_#{entity.is_a?(Object) ? 'singleton_' : ''}method".to_sym

    entity.send(definition_method_name, "#{attr_name}=".to_sym) do |value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr_name}", value)
    end

    entity.send(definition_method_name, attr_name.to_sym) do
      instance_variable_get("@#{attr_name}")
    end
  end

  def call(method_name)
    @klass_obj.send(method_name)
    universal_attr_accessor(@klass_obj, method_name)
  end

end

k = ReadCsv.new('Input.csv')
p k.call 'name' 
p k.call 'age'  
p k.call 'city' . # until here code works just fine
k.name = 'XYZ' # I am not able to assign new key value for this dynamic method called at runtime.
k.age = 25
p k.call 'name'
p k.call 'age'
```

Expected Result :

```
k = ReadCsv.new('Input.csv')
p k.call 'name'  # ['Chris','Matt']
p k.call 'age'  #  [23,23]
p k.call 'city' . # ['NYC','SFO']
k.name = 'XYZ' 
k.age = 25
p k.call 'name' # ['Chris','Matt','XYZ']
p k.call 'age'  # [23,23,25]
```

Comment: That does not sound like the solution of the problem you stated. "Construct an array of objects and associate each object with the row of a csv file." - it sounds to me that after you read `persons.csv`, you should be left with an array of `Person` objects, each of which responds to e.g. `#name` and `#name=` (so you could say `persons[0].name = "Abhinav"`). Not one gigantic object that contains arrays of columns; and in particular, I see no mention of a function named `call` to get a column.

Comment: If you make your class a `Struct`, you will get all the accessors for free: `the_class = Struct.new(field_names)`. Then it is easy to map `CSV::Row` objects into and array of `the_class` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I have a bit of time, here's the solution with a custom class, as opposed to `OpenStruct`:

```
require 'csv'

module CSVReader
  def self.read(file_name)
    class_name = File.basename(file_name, ".csv").capitalize
    rows = CSV.read(file_name)
    the_class = Struct.new(*rows.shift.map(&:to_sym))
    Object.const_set(class_name, the_class)
    rows.map { |row| the_class.new(*row) }
  end
end


array = CSVReader.read("person.csv")
p array
# => [#<struct Person name="Bob", department="Engineering", salary="1000">, #<struct Person name="Jane", department="Sales", salary="2000">, #<struct Person name="John", department="Management", salary="5000">]
bob = array[0]
p bob
# => #<struct Person name="Bob", department="Engineering", salary="1000">
bob.department = "Inhuman Resources"
p bob.department
# => "Inhuman Resources"
p bob
# => #<struct Person name="Bob", department="Inhuman Resources", salary="1000">
```

Answer (score 1):

As per comment from @Amadan, here is a barebone solution of what you are trying to achieve. It uses `OpenStruct` instead of custom classes.

```
persons =
  CSV.parse(<<~ROWS, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol)
    name,department,salary
    Bob,Engineering,1000
    Jane,Sales,2000
    John,Management,5000
  ROWS
persons =
  persons.map(&:to_h).map(&OpenStruct.method(:new))
```

---

Resulting in:

```
#⇒ [#<OpenStruct name="Bob", department="Engineering", salary="1000">,
#   #<OpenStruct name="Jane", department="Sales", salary="2000">,
#   #<OpenStruct name="John", department="Management", salary="5000">]
```

And:

```
persons.first.name
#⇒ "Bob"
persons.first.name = "Mary"
#⇒ "Mary"
persons.first.name
#⇒ "Mary"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aleksei, Can you please also specify.. how to implement it on dynamic method here ? I was not able to figure out correct implementation and calling it inside call method as universal_attr_accessor(@klass_obj, method_name) is not working out.

Comment: You don’t need anything else; check the last snippet, all the methods are implemented for you out of the box. Or you might do `def universal_attr_accessor(obj, m, *args); obj.public_send(m, *args); end`